# Update mysql root user password?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

How can I update the root users authentication string in mysql 5.7?

I've tried:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string='-?"adBSasfasdfAWw-9?^2}-H'%KLP@' WHERE user='root';
```

But no luck.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: There's a glaring syntax error in your attempt there. Be careful when assigning passwords with `'` in them. Don't forget you can do `mysqladmin password XXXX` to assign your password as well.

Answer (score 1):

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assigning-passwords.html

And use `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost';`

Don't update MySQL password data directly, because different authentication plugins may hash the password differently. `SET PASSWORD` takes this into account.

And don't post your root password on the internet. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I rejigged that root password as an example, the set password line, gives an error,  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Sounds like you didn't close a quote.